# insert blank first row

Tags: excel, vba

i am using below vba formula to inset new row keeping formula as it is in A1 row.

```
Sub move_and_delete_rows()
Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(i)
            With .Range("A1")
                .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                .CurrentRegion.Copy
            End With
            .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Range("A21").EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

above formula working fine. but that it should insert row say from column A to column J. after J column no insertion of row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) If you want to insert the whole row but copy only 10 cells** from A1 to J1 then instead of this line:

```
.CurrentRegion.Copy
```

try this line:

```
.Resize(1,10).Copy
```

**2) But if you want to insert only 10 cells below range `A1:j1`** then instead of this line:

```
.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

try this line:

```
.Offset(1,0).Resize(1,10).Insert
```

**You can combine both options** if you want to copy and insert only 10 cells.